# Is it possible to bypass ATA password?

Tags: ssd, self-encrypting-drive, opal, ata-security, tcg-opal

I am using TrueCrypt but I want to buy SSD with SED, it's Samsung 840 Evo. After firmware upgrade it "supports advanced data security features(TCG/Opal and IEEE 1667)".

If I set ATA password, would it make my SSD secure enough? I am not talking about NSA etc. I am just curious if you are able to crack it and read data from drive?

I have Lenovo Z500 - no TPM chip I guess and only 8 characters HDD Password...

Comment: Does the ATA password actually encrypt anything?

Comment: "AES encryption is always active on an 840 or 840 Pro Series SSD. In order to benefit from the encryption feature, however, the user must enable an ATA password to limit access to the data. Failure to do so will render AES-encryption ineffective – akin to having a safe but leaving the door wide open." - http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/about/whitepaper06.html

Comment: Ah, I have one of these drives myself but didn't know that. It's confusing though--are our drives unreadable in other systems?

Comment: A quick search says ATA passwords are easily defeated--exploits that are cheaper than brute force.

Comment: Your drive is readable in other systems because it's not protected by ATA password...If I understand correctly, SED uses ATA password for protecting Encryption Key stored in disk controller (which is used for encrypt/decrypt data on disk). So if you don't set ATA password, your Encryption Key is not protected

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I get it. By default it will decrypt on the fly

Comment: @Quak ATA passwords have nothing to do with SEDs in general. MEK is protected once you enable encryption and set the passphrase. _Some_ old SSDs might utilize ATA Security feature set such as using reusing ATA password.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to bypass ATA password?

Yes. So even though the encryption is super secure, it's a bit like having an unbreakable safe to store valuables in, and hide the key in plain sight.

Commercial forensic / data recovery tool breaking an ATA password within minutes:

[image]

So rather than relying on ATA use a different method to manage the built-in hardware encryption.

Comment: It's not as simple as this. Some earlier SEDs like Samsung 840 used ATA password as TCG Opal SID password. But Opal encryption has nothing to do with ATA Security as such. It's an interesting question what will happen to Samsung 840 encrypted data if you try to bypass ATA password. Only a test can tell. I agree with "don't rely on ATA" though.